# How can I write the data coming through a unix pipe to the current terminal window?

Tags: bash, pipe

I am looking for a similar functionality to `pv`, but instead of outputting stats, I would just like to get the whole pipe throughput printed to the terminal. Is this possible, e.g. with `pv` or `tee` or some clever stream redirection?

Comment: yes, more specifically the Terminal on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### View pipe content in the same terminal window

On Linux, you can use

```
 someCommand | tee /dev/tty | anotherCommand
```

For example

```
 { for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo $i; sleep 0.5; done; } | tee /dev/tty | grep 3
```

prints

```
1
2
3
3
4
```

The `3` appears twice, because `grep` printed it too. Because you cannot tell which output came from `tee` and which from `grep` I would recommend to use this pipe content viewer only if the pipe does not print anything on its own, e.g. if the last command in the pipe redirects to a file.

#### View pipe content in another terminal window

Alternatively, you can view the pipe's content in another terminal, using

```
# first, execute this in the terminal that should view the pipe's content
mkfifo /tmp/mypipeviewer
cat /tmp/mypipeviewer
```

```
# then run your pipe in another terminal
someCommand | tee /tmp/mypipeviewer | anotherCommand
```

This only works as long as `cat` is running.  If you exit `cat` (for instance by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or by closing its terminal) the pipe will exit early.

Comment: This connects it to the user's current terminal, not the system console.

Comment: I think this is what OP wanted, as they said *"`the Terminal on Ubuntu 20.04`"*.

Comment: Nice! (If I really need to tell the two outputs apart, I can also add a `sed` as the last step to prefix the last command's output with some tag).